# Размер типа с виртуальным базовым классом

Tags: c++

Пусть у нас есть такое наследование:

```
struct B {};
struct DB : B {       
    int k{};
    //int n{};  
};
```

(Я специально закоментировал второй член, чтобы рассмотреть `DB` с  одним членом как **случай №1**, а с двумя членами, как **случай №2**).

Очевидно, что для `DB` будет выделено

- случай №1. `4 байт`
- случай №2. `8 байт`

А если базовый класс виртуальный, то **64_битном приложении**, где `sizeof(int) == 4`, получаем:

- случай №1. `16 байт`
- случай №2. тоже `16 байт`

Т.е.  выравнивание полей тут уже по `8 байт,` а не 4. И, соответственно, для  наследника:

```
struct DDB : DB {      
   int p{};            
};
```

В случаи с обычным наследованием будет выделено:

- случай №1. `8 байт`
- случай №2. `12 байт`

а в случаи с виртуальным базовым классом  `sizeof(DDB) == 24`(для  `DDB` тоже выравнивание _ **8**).

**Вопрос:**
Как это понять _ почему при виртуальном наследовании поля выравниваются по размеру указателья ?

Answer (score 2):

Может быть, просто выравнивается по наибольшему члену? А виртуальный класс первым же членом имеет указатель на vtable? Потому что и без него при указателях подлучаеся то же самое:

В Visual Studio для 64 разрялов

```
struct B {};
struct DB : B {       8 байт
    int k{};
    int n{};
};

struct EB : B {       16 байт
    int *k{};
    int n{};
};
struct FB : B {       16 байт
    int k{};
    int *n{};
};
```

Но если сказать `#pragma pack(4)` они сразу становятся 8 12 и 12 байт.

Comment: Ну да, если есть указатель, выравниваться будут по размеру слова, но  тут  сначала нужно знать, что виртуальный класс имеет неявный указатель, Про этот указатель рассказать было бы неплохо, потому что не ясно наличие vptr в виртуальном классе  зависит от реализации компилятора или  нет.

Comment: Суть в том, что выравниваение добавляет пустые байты, также в конец структуры, для того чтобы в случае массива `DB[3]` начало каждого элемента массива было правильно воровнено. Т.е. размер структуры должен быть кратен неаибольшему значению выравнивание для членов структуры.